# Rally grid column renderer change onUpdate

Tags: extjs, rally

I have a rallygrid that I am populating with data and some custom columns on it.  One of the columns I want to be a plain text representation of the month or quarter the portfolio item is associated with based on its planned start and end dates:

```
{
    text: 'Date Range',
    dataIndex: 'PlannedStartDate',
    renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
        var date = new Date(value);
        return App._getSpan(new Date(record.data.PlannedStartDate), new Date(record.data.PlannedEndDate));
}
```

The _getSpan() method works, and when the page loads the grid is populated nicely.  However, when I do an inline edit on one of the other fields displayed in the grid (owner, name, etc) when the change is saved, the record updates and does not fetch the PlannedStartDate and PlannedEndDate fields, so when I call

```
new Date()
```

on them, it turns back the clock to time 0 (Dec 31 1969).

My messy solution to this was to check if the Start and End dates were set in the renderer function, and if not, to use another query to find the object I am looking for by its ID and fetch all the necessary information.  The query I developed had an error, and for some reason, that means that when I changed some other field, it would save the state but not try to render this column again with bad data!

Having an error in your code to make it work is quite counter intuitive though - what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to use record.raw rather than record.data - the info in raw remained intact

```
{
    text: 'Date Range',
    dataIndex: 'PlannedStartDate',
    renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
        var date = new Date(value);
        return App._getSpan(new Date(record.raw.PlannedStartDate), new Date(record.raw.PlannedEndDate));
}
```